# Read numbers from file to two significant digits?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream basketFile;
    basketFile.open("basket.txt");

    double price;

    while (!basketFile.eof()) {
        basketFile >> price;
        cout << price << endl;
    }

}
```

basket.txt

```
27.9933
18.992
9.754
11.2543
```

Anyway I can make the numbers appear to only two significant digits?  Also, if I want to round a number up how would I do that?  For example, if I had the numbers 6.66 and 4.33 I want the 6.66->6.70 and 4.33->4.30.  Any help?

Comment: You don't _read_ the numbers with a specific precision, instead you set the number of digits when you want to _print_ / _write_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/).

For rounding a number, see [`round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round).

Also, if you decide to round to 0.1 precision, I believe you can just append the zero `0` after the rounded result.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void p(double x) {
  cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << x << 0 << endl;
}

int main() {
  p(27.9933);
  p(18.992);
  p(9.754);
  p(11.2543);
  p(6.66);
  p(4.33);
  return 0;
}
```

The code above outputs:

```
28.00
19.00
9.80
11.30
6.70
4.30
```

Hope this is what you want.